# installe zlib library still getting error missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, zlib

Im getting error:

```
CMake Error at E:/Program Files/CMAKE/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

I runned this command while getting this error message:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$USERPROFILE\desktop-client -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DNO_SHIBBOLETH=1
```

I downloaded zlib.net zlib archive and opened with visual studio 2019 and rebuilded it. (Didn't work) Then I tryied this https://github.com/horta/zlib.install

OS - Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I think you have ZLib installed in your Download folder, and it's in a non-standard location since CMake cannot find it.

Set the location in CMake-gui:

1. Click the 'Advanced' checkbox near the top
2. You can see the ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR options
3. Set the correct path of ZLIB library